# How do I pick data from two tables with many to many relationships in PowerQuery / Excel Data Model?

Tags: excel, pivot, powerquery, powerpivot, datamodel

this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, let's see how this goes!

I am trying to connect a scenario manager for different sizes of assets to their belonging cost timeseries so that I can calculate the cashflow of the asset configuration belonging to a certain scenario.

This is what (in short version) both my tables that need to be connected look like:

ScenarioManager:

| Scenario | SG | HOB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scenario1 | SG280 | HB200 |
| Scenario2 | SG320 | HOB160 |

CostSheet:

| Config | Subtype | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SG280 | SG | -500 | -180 | -250 | -680 |
| SG320 | SG | -600 | -700 | -345 | -880 |
| HOB200 | HOB | -300 | -680 | -500 | -320 |
| HOB160 | HOB | -250 | -300 | -260 | -700 |

I load the data to the Data Model in Excel and unpivoted SG and HOB in the Scenario Manager as Config and then connected Config from the ScenarioManager to Config in the CostSheet. However that way I can't see the data in a PivotTable the way I want to. To achieve the view I need I need to create a second CostSheet where the Years columns are unpivoted as well. However when I go forward like this the PivotTable doesn' show me the correct values, instead it shows the sum of all Configs for the specific year.

The table I want to create should look like this:

Filter: Scenario1

| Config | Subtype | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SG280 | SG | -500 | -180 | -250 | -680 |
| HOB200 | HOB | -300 | -680 | -500 | -320 |

etc. for every scenario that I have.

[I uploaded the original file with the data here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/skc38wtq09f0pkslwhqav/Data-Example.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=m88ygv66gh23mvxb4b578346r)

I hope you guys can help me and thank you in advance!

Best
Julia

Comment: Could you use `VLOOKUP`, `INDEX MATCH` or `XLOOKUP` to do this?  Seems like you want to match a value from Table A with a Value in Table B.  `VLOOKUP`: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function  `INDEX MATCH`: https://exceljet.net/index-and-match  `XLOOKUP`: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function You can use any of these to easily match `SG` from `Scenario Manager` Table with `Config` from `CostSheet` Table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I could but I would like to avoid using formulas as I will be working with > 200.000 Datapoints. We are currently already using formulas like VLOOKUP etc, however this causes my model to overload and I am investigating ways on how to reduce the size of my model by applying the Data Model and Power Query functionalities. Do you have any idea on how the issue would work without using formulas?

Comment: Thank you for the sample tables. Note the typo in the `ScenarioManager` table: "HB200"

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query, once you have unpivoted the `ScenarioManager` table, you can merge it with the `CostSheet` table on the `Config` column. Here is the Power Query M code, where `ScenarioManager` and `CostSheet` are queries that import the sample tables given above:

```
let
    Source = ScenarioManager,
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Scenario"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns", {"Value"}, CostSheet, {"Config"}, "CostSheet", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded CostSheet" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "CostSheet", {"Subtype", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024"}, {"Subtype", "2021", "2022", "2023", "2024"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded CostSheet",{{"Value", "Config"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Then you can load this query as a table and filter it using the `Scenario` column.

[image: table]

If you prefer having a PivotTable, you can add a step to unpivot the table and then load it to a PivotTable instead:

```
    ...
    #"Unpivoted Columns2" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Renamed Columns", {"Scenario", "Config", "Subtype"}, "Year", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Columns2"
```

The values might be aggregated by count by default when applying this to your full dataset. Aggregating by sum will produce the desired outcome seeing as there are only single values to sum for each `Config`-`Year` pair.

[image: pivottable]