# Need Excel Help: Text File Import that has Multiple Tables

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am having trouble pulling weather station data from the web. I'm accessing a text file that has all of the data from each station in one file. When I use power query, I'm able to pull in all the data, but it's all in one worksheet. Ideally, I'd be able to add a column that lists the station name so I may use a V/Hlookup function, or I would be able to reformat the table so that all the data from each station was on one row. Any suggestions are appreciated.
[Screen shot of source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxRtF.png) [image: Possible Excel format after manipulation]

Here is the link to the source file: http://wfas.net/nfdr/output/ndfd_predserv_fcst.txt

Comment: Provide the source data (link to text file, copy pasted, etc.)

Comment: If instead of an image you provide a small sample table like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68669000/14148248) it would make it much easier for someone to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the source file, this made it possible for me to answer your question. Don't hesitate to comment under my answer if you have any questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest extracting the name and metadata of each station (stored in the first row) into one table and extract the weather data into a separate table and link them with a *Station ID* column. If the metadata is of no use to you apart from the station name, the following example can easily be adjusted accordingly.

After importing the text file into the Power Query Editor, the columns first need to be split. In the following example, this is done by using positions, which works fine except for the *LOESS HILLS TNC BROK* station name which is one character longer than all other names causing a misalignment of the metadata with the columns. I leave the issue of solving this up to you.

The following example is carried out on a sample of data imported from the [linked source](http://wfas.net/nfdr/output/ndfd_predserv_fcst.txt) accessed on Saturday 2021-09-18 and consisting of just the first 3 weather stations. The sample is included in the M code below, here is what the first 20 rows look like:

[image: sample_raw_data]

Here is the M code used to prepare the data before separating it into one table for station metadata and one for the weather data. The key part is to create an ID column for the stations. In the step named `#"Integer-Divided Column"`, the `11*13` corresponds to 11 (days of measurements) multiplied by 13 (variables: station name, *Fcst Dy*, *Max RH (%)*, etc.):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("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", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Split Column by Positions" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 19, 26, 34, 45, 55, 65, 74, 83, 92, 101, 110}), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5", "Column1.6", "Column1.7", "Column1.8", "Column1.9", "Column1.10", "Column1.11", "Column1.12"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Column by Positions", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Blank Rows",{{"Column1.1", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.2", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.3", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.4", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.5", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.6", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.7", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.8", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.9", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.10", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.11", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.12", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted All Columns Except First One" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Trimmed Text", {"Column1.1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Index to Create Station ID" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted All Columns Except First One", "Station ID", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index to Create Station ID", {{"Station ID", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 11*13), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Integer-Divided Column",{"Station ID", "Column1.1", "Attribute", "Value"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

Here is the result for the first 20 rows:

[image: data_prep]

Now you can create a reference to this query (named *DataPrep*) and use the function to remove alternate to create a table containing only the metadata of the stations. The rows with blank cells can be filtered out before pivoting the table. In the following code, `132` corresponds to 11 (days of measurements) multiplied by 12 (variables: *Fcst Dy*, *Max RH (%)*, etc.):

```
let
    Source = DataPrep,
    #"Removed Alternate Rows" = Table.AlternateRows(Source,11,132,11),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Alternate Rows", each ([Value] <> "")),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Filtered Rows", List.Distinct(#"Filtered Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Here is the result for the first 4 columns, the columns still need to be renamed appropriately:

[image: stations_metadata]

The table containing the weather data is created in a similar way except that this time the column *Column1.1* is the one that is pivoted and the missing values entered as `-99` are filtered out after pivoting the table to remove the associated dates along with them:

```
let
    Source = DataPrep,
    #"Removed Alternate Rows" = Table.AlternateRows(Source,0,11,132),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Alternate Rows", List.Distinct(#"Removed Alternate Rows"[Column1.1]), "Column1.1", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Pivoted Column", each ([#"Max RH (%)"] <> "-99")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here is the result for the first 20 rows and the first 4 columns:

[image: weather_data]

The data is now ready for further processing or analysis. The tables can be loaded to the Data Model to create a PivotTable using Power Pivot to get the result in the screenshot you have shared. Alternatively, you could edit the queries above to get the names of the stations instead of the station ID in the weather data table and then create a PivotTable just from that table without needing Power Pivot.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This is perfect. I appreciate the assistance.